# HP 8570p - connecting two monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have VGA out to my monitor (Dell 2007FPb), and then DVI-D from first monitor to second monitor (Dell E1910).

The VGA works fine.  The second monitor gives message that `NO-DVI-D cable`. Huh?  Cable is plugged in.  I am NOT using a docking station.  Is my cable bad?

Comment: Ummm... Yeah... monitors don't work that way. Why not get a dual head video card?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You simply cannot daisychain monitors like that. You connected two dvi inputs together. There is simply no signal to the second monitor. You would need another output at the PC or something like thunderbolt that supports daisychaining